# Winforms DataGridView columns from datasource

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, datagridview

I have base class and some inherited classes, like this:

```
public abstract class Base
{
    public long ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual string Description { get { return "Base"; } }
}

public class A : Base
{
    public override string Description { get { return "A"; } }
}

public class B : Base
{
    private string extraInfo;

    public override string Description { get { return "B"; } }

    public string ExtraInfo
    {
        get { return extraInfo; }
        set { extraInfo = value; }
    }
}
```

I have collection of these objects and I set this collection to `DataSource` of `DataGridView`. Then, columns of `DataGridView` will be created by `Base` class's properties (`ID`, `Name`. `Description`). Is there any way to reflect also concrete implementation properties?

```
    List<Base> items = new List<Base>();
    DataGridView dgv = new DataGridView();
    dgv.DataSource = new BindingList<Base>(items);
```

In this case, I want also column for `ExtraInfo` property of class `B`.

Comment: If the source contains only `B` type objects, then bind `BindingList<B>`.

Comment: Ok I forgot to mention that I don't know the type of objects on compile time. I need it like this (`List<Base>`)

Comment: Then you'll get only the `Base` properties. WF data binding uses the static type information from `IList<T>` implementation for extracting the properties (hence the columns) - it does not check the actual type of the elements of the list. And that's the correct behavior - if your list contains `A` instance, what `ExtraInfo` will show for them.

Answer (score 0):

Inherit class B too:

```
public class Base
{
    public long ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual string Description { get { return "Base"; } }
}

public class A : Base
{
    public override string Description { get { return "A"; } }
}

public class B : Base
{
    private string extraInfo;

    public override string Description { get { return "B"; } }

    public string ExtraInfo
    {
        get { return extraInfo; }
        set { extraInfo = value; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry I've fixed it in question already. This is not issue unfortunately.